# How to find all documents containing a certain value with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm using nodejs and mongodb.
x is a variable containing a string (certain color). now, I would like to create a query (in nodejs) that retrieves all docs which their colors field (which is a list of strings, in this case a list of colors) contains the string x. 
How should I write it in nodejs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, because in the first paragraph you are asking for an OR relation, but your example describes an AND relation.

When you want to find all documents which have red OR green, you have to use the $in operator:

```
db.collection.find({ colors: { $in:[ "red", "green" ]} });
```

When you want to find all documents which have red AND green (and maybe also others), you have to use $all:

```
db.collection.find({ colors: { $all:[ "red", "green" ]} });
```

Source: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries

Comment: If Philipp's response didn't answer your question, it's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Could you post a code snippet?

Comment: In addition, examples of your documents, as well as the expected result of your query, will help us find a solution.